# Custom Build Apache, where is a2enmod or equivalent command?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, spdy

I compiled my own copy of Apache 2.2 for testing SPDY and installed locally in my Linux home directory.  However, I can't find the a2enmod as part of the install.  Where can I find that script or can someone show me the equivalent?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can always copy in the script from Debian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a2enmod is a Debian-ism, and isn't used for anything other than Debian's (or Debianlike) apache packages.

Your equivalent is to edit [`$PREFIX/conf/httpd.conf`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html#customize) and add your site configuration.